# How can I fetch arrays values in a list of items using GatsbyJS?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

For each post in this blog, there's an array for categories and tags that should be displayed as meta information for the reader. Thing is I'm not handling this right.

I've been trying to map these arrays with this code:

```
<ul>
  {frontmatter.map(({ categories }, i )=> (
     <li>
        <Link 
          className={`
            (...tailwind classes...)
          `} 
           key={i} 
           to={categories}>
          {categories}
        </Link>
      </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Although the terminal showing me this success message...
[image: Terminal]

...the browser tells me `TypeError: frontmatter.map is not a function`.
[image: Browser results]

I'm guessing I misunderstood the map function, but reading about it I can't really manage it to work.

The query is this:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      fields {
        slug
      }
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
        path
                title
        featuredImage {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
                type
                categories
                tags                
      }
    }
  }
`
```

It is returning as expected:
[image: GraphQL results]

Also, there's a page for each category displaying it's posts. Their slugs are */categorias/[category-name]*. So, in that code above for mapping them, I'll probably need to set Link `to="/categorias/${categories}"` or something. Not sure about what, but since I'm not even getting a list with simple names, that's another kind of problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

[This is the blogPost.js in its full content.](https://github.com/edueter/gatsby-theme-cripto/blob/master/src/templates/blogPost.js)

Comment: As you can see (kind of brackets) in playground `frontmatter` is an object with `categories` and `tags` arrays you can iterate on. `frontmatter.tags.map((tag) => <Tag name={tag} key={tag} />)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @xadm. I see it. As in Robin response, it's not working. I'm reading about it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query response has this shape:

```
"data": {
  "markdownRemark": {
    // ...
    "frontmatter": {
      "date": "...",
      "path": "...",
      "categories": [
        "cat-a",
        "cat-b"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can not map over `frontmatter` because it is not an iterator. More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

What you want is this: (map over the categories array)

```html
<ul>
  {frontmatter.categories.map((category, i) => (
     <li>
        <Link 
          className={`
            (...tailwind classes...)
          `} 
           key={i} 
           to={category}>
          {category}
        </Link>
      </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Robin! It didn't work. I got this message in browser telling the element should be a string or a class/function, but it got undefined instead. I've tried this same thing before, I guess. Forgot to mention. Not sure what's wrong. Going to read that link you sent. Thanks!

Comment: Let me try to reproduce locally :)

Comment: Sure! Thanks. You can reach a blog post @ [sample](http://localhost:8000/blog/my-first-blog-post/)

Comment: This is a different error, because you're trying to import the Gatsby `Link` component from `react`. Fixed by switching to `import { Link } from "gatsby"` (see [this line](https://github.com/edueter/gatsby-theme-cripto/blob/abee194bb702712597fdee9c9874965227af0790/src/templates/blogPost.js#L1)). I think my answer solves the issue described in your question :)

Comment: Closing note: in my answer I linked to the [the `.map` docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), but if you want some more human-readable explanations and examples of it, I strongly recommend [Tania Rascia's article about it](https://www.taniarascia.com/real-world-examples-of-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript/). Happy learning!

Comment: Ok, I'm embarrassed now. hahaha Thanks for pointing that out and for the link to this article. Will be reading it right now!

Comment: @EduardoOliveira next time render text only at start ...`{frontmatter.categories.map((category) => { return (<span key={category}>{category}</span>) } )}`

Comment: @xadm noted! Thanks!